# Integrate the absolute value of a function along the orbital period

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I need to integrate the absolute value of this functions

1.f1=

```
 (1/(4 a^5 (-1 + 
   e^2)^5))625 B d dw^2 L \[Pi] Sqrt[-a (-1 + 
    e^2) \[Mu]] \[Sigma] (R + e R Cos[f])^3 (11 e Cos[f - \[Omega]] + 
   3 e^2 Cos[2 f - \[Omega]] + 12 Cos[\[Omega]] + 
   3 e^2 Cos[\[Omega]] - 8 e Cos[f + \[Omega]] - 
   32 Cos[2 f + \[Omega]] - 15 e^2 Cos[2 f + \[Omega]] - 
   47 e Cos[3 f + \[Omega]] - 15 e^2 Cos[4 f + \[Omega]]) Sin[i]
```

2.f2=

```
 -(1/(4 a^5 (-1 + e^2)^5))
 625 B d dw^2 L \[Pi] Sqrt[-a (-1 + e^2) \[Mu]] \[Sigma] (R + 
    e R Cos[f])^3 Sin[
   i] (-11 e Sin[f - \[Omega]] - 3 e^2 Sin[2 f - \[Omega]] + 
    12 Sin[\[Omega]] + 5 e^2 Sin[\[Omega]] + 30 e Sin[f + \[Omega]] + 
    32 Sin[2 f + \[Omega]] + 21 e^2 Sin[2 f + \[Omega]] + 
    47 e Sin[3 f + \[Omega]] + 15 e^2 Sin[4 f + \[Omega]])
```

3. f3=

   `-((3750 B d dw^2 e L \[Pi] R^3 Sqrt[-a (-1 + e^2) \[Mu]] \[Sigma] (1 + e Cos[f])^4 Cos[i] Sin[f])/(a^5 (-1 + e^2)^5))`

multiplied by

f4=

```
(a^2 (1 - e^2)^2)/(Sqrt[a (1 - e^2) \[Mu]] (1 + e Cos[f])^2).
```

I mean the definite integral of

int{|f1|*f4 df},

int{|f2|*f4 df},

int{|f3|*f4 df},

from 0 to 2 Pi.
When I try this, Mathematica keeps running for a long time and does not show a result.
All parameters are PositiveReals, and the variable is f.

Sorry if I'm making mistakes in the comment, It's the second time I post here, the first was 3 years ago...

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. You can fix syntax errors such as a period at the end of `f4`. Also check `Exp` that is written as `E` not `e`, if that is what you mean. The first Integral comes to $\frac{1875 \left(8+3 e^2\right) \pi ^2 B d \text{dw}^2 L R^3 \sigma  \sin (i) \cos (\omega )}{4 \left(e^2-1\right)^3 a^3}$.

Comment: What constraints exist on the parameters/variables? Are any positive? Bound on some interval? As a general rule, if possible simplify the integrands prior to integration using constraints as assumptions. And include these assumptions in the integral.

Comment: plz post your Math problem alongside your code!
i think @Syed pointed something important to you!

Comment: You can enter Euler's constant as Esc e e Esc and the imaginary unit as Esc i i Esc or use capital E and capital I respectively.

Comment: No Syed, it's not Euler's constant. It's the orbital eccentricity, That's why I didn't use 'Exp[]'. With RealAbs, I've found the same result as you, however comparing with the numerical integral it's not a match.

Comment: One cannot guess the numerical outcome unless the values of all the constants are available. Please describe your problem, name the constants, name the integrals along with `Abs` or `RealAbs`, add the tag `physics`, show your code as it currently is. This way, you can get more focused responses. Thanks.